# How can I prevent duplicate entries in Jtable and MYSQL(database)?

Tags: java, mysql, duplicates, jtable, try-catch

**Well the main problem here is, the detection of the duplicate entries in the Jtable, the Detection of duplicate entries will work when your enter the SAME/IDENTICAL data for the third time. It would not work in the second time and duplicate.**

*how can i add a unique constrain in my mysql? i dont know how to do it. Please let me have a specific instructions on how to execute it*

[2nd try (duplicate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRoDD.png)

[3rd try(the detection works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02yDr.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fI2u.png)

JAVA NETBEANS

DATABASE: MYSQL

**I think the problem would be the try-catch part which is the part that I dont understand. Thank You in Advance.**

Heres my codes:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     String first = firstname.getText();
     String last = lastname.getText();
      String gen = gender.getText();
     String strand = cboStrand.getSelectedItem().toString();
     String aged = age.getText();
     String add = address.getText();


    try{
       String sql;
       sql = "INSERT INTO idusjavanew"
                + "(fname,lname,sex,strand,age,address)"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";           
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/idusjavanew?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
       pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, firstname.getText());
        pst.setString(2, lastname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, gender.getText());
        pst.setString(4, cboStrand.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(5, age.getText());
        pst.setString(6, address.getText());

        String selectQuery; 
        selectQuery = "select * from idusjavanew where fname ='"+first+"' and lname='"+last+"'";
        System.out.println(selectQuery);
        rs = pst.executeQuery(selectQuery);
        System.out.println(rs.next());

        if (rs.next()==false){
         pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Information has been recorded!");
        showTableData();
        }
       else{

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Information already added!");
        showTableData();
        } 
      }   

      catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
      } 
            showTableData();


}
```

Comment: Just add a unique constraint in mysql and check for a duplicate key error after the insert.

Comment: @Shadow can you give me specific instructions on how to do it? I dont have a clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `next()` twice on your result set once in print statement and once in `if`, that is causing the issue.

So according to your current code if you already have an entry the 1st call to `next()` will point it to that entry and the second call will return false. That is why it detects duplicate on third row entry.

So just remove `System.out.println(rs.next());` and your code should work as intended.